# php symlink not work

Tags: php, symlink

i need simple create symlink with php symlink function, but it's just not work... Here is example of my code:

```
$target = "photogallery/some-gallery";  
$link = "photogallery/link-to-some-gallery";  
symlink($target, $link);
```

PHP script is in the root of the web and photogallery is subdirectory:
/var/www/web/test.php
/var/www/web/photogallery/some-gallery

I try to set chmod for photogallery to 0777, use absolute paths, mix absolute and relative paths, enable +FollowSymlinks on apache, use parameters in reverse order, but symlink always fail with no error. If I try

```
exec('ln -s '.$absoluteTarget.' '.$absoluteLink)
```

is symlink created successfully, but this isn't allowed if webhoster is paranoic...

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When you say "no error", do you mean that [symlink](http://php.net/symlink) returns true? Have you enabled PHP to log or display errors?

Comment: What your platform is?